# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - processing Form values

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm learning Spring Boot+thymeleaf at the same time, so apologies if this is a noob question - however i haven't seen an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm building a questionnaire of Question objects. Each Question object has properties like description, weightage, and a TreeMap of answer options with Pts for the answer as the Key, and the option text as the value.
The Question sequence to be displayed matters, and the option sequence matters as well(hence the TreeMap for options).
I iterate over the List of questions in the form like this(this shows just one question and iteration over the options for that question) :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/frm}" th:object="${scorer}" method="post">
<table>
    <tr th:each="question, iterStat: ${questionList}">
        <td th:text="${question.getQuestionText()}"></td>
        <td>
        <select th:field="*{answers}">
        <option th:each="option :${questionList[iterStat.index].getAnswerOptions()}" 
              th:value="${option.getKey()}" 
              th:text= "${option.getValue()}">
        </option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

So, here are my questions:
Since the order of the answers is important for me(i need to send back text that is dependent on what they selected for each question), is there a way to retrieve(on POST) a sorted map of (question,chosen answer) in the order of questions displayed without having to name each question field?
What does the form-bound bean need to look like? I guess I'm also looking for some insight into how Spring Boot does its magic here?